# Search String and Return Line PHP

Tags: php, line, file-get-contents, strpos

I'm trying to search a PHP file for a string and when that string is found I want to return the whole LINE that the string is on.  Here is my example code.  I'm thinking I would have to use explode but cannot figure that out.

```
$searchterm =  $_GET['q'];

$homepage = file_get_contents('forms.php');

 if(strpos($homepage, "$searchterm") !== false)
 {
 echo "FOUND";

 //OUTPUT THE LINE

 }else{

 echo "NOTFOUND";
 }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just read the whole file as array of lines using [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function.

```
function getLineWithString($fileName, $str) {
    $lines = file($fileName);
    foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
        if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
            return $line;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Short circuits on the first occurence of the magic string.  Also does not return the line, only the line number that the string happened on.

Comment: I was able to get the contents of that line by echoing the $line.  Works great!

Comment: Ou, sorry I thought you wanted just the line number, now it's fixed.

Comment: @Martin  What if I need not the current line content but the next line content? cheers :)

Comment: This will be problematic if the file is gigantic

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fgets()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.fgets.php) function to get the line number.

Something like :

```
$handle = fopen("forms.php", "r");
$found = false;
if ($handle) 
{
    $countline = 0;
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false)
    {
        if (strpos($buffer, "$searchterm") !== false)
        {
            echo "Found on line " . $countline + 1 . "\n";
            $found = true;
        }
        $countline++;
    }
    if (!$found)
        echo "$searchterm not found\n";
    fclose($handle);
}
```

If you still want to use [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php), then do something like :

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("forms.php");
$exploded_page = explode("\n", $homepage);
$found = false;

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($exploded_page); ++$i)
{
    if (strpos($buffer, "$searchterm") !== false)
    {
        echo "Found on line " . $countline + 1 . "\n";
        $found = true;
    }
}
if (!$found)
    echo "$searchterm not found\n";
```

Comment: What is the 4096 for?

Comment: @JohnMagnolia http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php - It's the buffer size. It will read 4096 -1 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `file` rather than `file_get_contents` you can loop through an array line by line searching for the text and then return that element of the array.

PHP  [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) documentation

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the fgets function to pull an individual line out and then search for the

```
<?PHP   
$searchterm =  $_GET['q'];
$file_pointer = fopen('forms.php');
while ( ($homepage = fgets($file_pointer)) !== false)
{
    if(strpos($homepage, $searchterm) !== false)
    {
        echo "FOUND";
        //OUTPUT THE LINE
    }else{
    echo "NOTFOUND";
    }
}
fclose($file_pointer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answered question about using regular expressions for your task.

[Get line number from preg_match_all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730867/get-line-number-from-preg-match-all)

Searching a file and returning the specified line numbers.