# file_get_contents + preg_match > find a line starting with a word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, file-get-contents

I do a `file_get_contents` to get a long file and I would like to find the line (there is only one) which starts with "MyParam" (for example).
I don't want to cut the file line by line, I want to do it with a `preg_match` only (or equivalent).
I've tried many things but no success.
Thanks in advance

FILE CONTENT

```
//some text
//some text
//MyParam "red"
//some text
MyParam "blue"
Some text
// Some text
```

And I would like to get `MyParam "blue"` only.

Comment: Show what you have tried please, also a sample of input is appreciated

Comment: Question understood partially... Can you post your input and expected output ?

Comment: preg match is slower than cutting line by line

Comment: Related: [Search String and Return Line PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9721952/2943403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must use a regex, you can do it as follows:

```
preg_match('/^MyParam[^\r\n]*/m', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Explanation:

- `[^\r\n]` - a character class that matches any characters other than a `\r` or `\n`.
- `m` - [multiline modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), which changes the meaning of `^` from "*assert position at the beginning of the **string***" to "*assert position at the beginning of **each line***".

Here, `$matches[0]` will contain the complete matched string (which in this case, is what you want).

Output:

```
string(14) "MyParam "blue""
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/146773)

Comment: @HamZa: wouldn't that include the newline as well? See here: https://eval.in/146768

Comment: Be creative and use `[^\r\n]*` :P

Comment: It works. Thanks. `preg_match` is really slow, or it's ok to do like that ?

Comment: @Peter: I'd say it depends on the length of your string. If the string is very long, I'd go with Casmir's solution as it reads line by line. In this case, it shouldn't really matter though.

Comment: @AmalMurali the file has around 1000 lines.

Comment: Thanks for the 'm' modifier! Saved some pulled follicles. :D

Answer (score 3):

Using file_get_contents is not the best choice here since you can **read** the file line by line

```
$handle = fopen("yourfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if (strpos($line, 'MyParam')===0) {
            echo 'found';
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'error opening the file';
} 
fclose($handle);
```

Note: if you need to extract a parameter value between quotes you can use:

```
$value = explode('"', $line, 3)[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

No need of regexp:

```
$pos = strpos($filecontent, "\nMyParam");
$endline = strpos($filecontent, "\n", $pos + 1);
$line = substr($filecontent, $pos + 1, $endline - $pos - 1) ;
```

Not tested, there is maybe an offset of +-1 in the string but it gives you the idea.

**Edit :** If you are sure that "MyParam" does not appears elsewhere in the file, you can remove the first "\n".

Answer (score 1):

You could use strpos() to find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.

https://www.php.net/strpos

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a couple of different approaches here.  The most important thing to consider is that you don't need to read the entire file into memory via `file_get_contents()`.  I would be inclined to just use shell commands to do this:

```
$file = '/path/to/file';
$search_pattern = '^MyParam';
$file_safe = escapeshellarg($file);
$pattern_safe = escapeshellarg($search_pattern);
$result = exec('grep ' . $pattern_safe . ' ' . $file_safe);
```

Alternately, you can read through the file one line at a time looking for the match:

```
$result = '';
$file = '/path/to/file';
$search = 'MyParam'; // note I am not using regex here as this is unnecessary in your case
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
if ($handle) {
    while($line = fgets($handle) !== false) {
        if (strpos($line, $search) === 0) { // exact match is important here
            $result = $line;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```